# When I make border in hover, another element slightly moved, how to make it stayed in their position?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make nav bar with flexbox, and when I add hover with border effect, the other element "moved". That's because the border only appear when hovered. How to make another elements stay in their position? in this case the categories, and the hr lines moved

[Here's the full code](https://codepen.io/ShiningAss/pen/qgVwPa)

```
.navbar{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 5px;
}
.navbar-menu{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.navbar-menu a{
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 8px;
}
.navbar-menu a:hover{
border: 2px solid #e84393;
color: white;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this trick

```css
.navbar-menu a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 2px solid transparent; /* add this line */
}
```

so basically initially border is transparent and on hover it only gets color visible and hence no mess up in position

Comment: thanks, it worked :)

Comment: great trick! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apply a transparent border in the normal state already;

Or use `outline` instead of border to begin with. (outline does not influence an elements size.)

Comment: thanks, it worked ^^